# Socket.io Ajax Request Returns intermittent 404

Tags: ajax, node.js, socket.io

I have a Node server that is handling users sessions, chatrooms, messaging, scraping among various other things.

Occasionally when sending messages from the website to the Node server the request returns a 404 error but it is very uncommon.

I am not sure how to debug this problem because it is so intermittent - 
Could this be due to load on the server from scraping pages?

Comment: I would if I knew what to post - the Ajax request works 99% of the time and fails randomly. What would you like to see?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I believe my suspicious were correct - I forked the intensive scraping tasks and I haven't encountered any 404 errors since.